# Boostrap parameter in random forest regressor?

Tags: machine-learning, python, scikit-learn, random-forest

There's one parameter in RandomForestRegressor which is `bootstrap`. By default
`bootstrap=True`

> bootstrap : boolean, optional (default=True)
>
> Whether bootstrap samples are used when building trees.

So from the docs if I set `bootstrap=False` then I guess bootstrap samples are not used but I'm really confused on what is bootstrap samples mean here?

There were explanations but it's really confusing. Can someone please explain it in a **simpler term**? And also does `bootstrap=True` help in improving the model accuracy?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Refer this answer on [stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40131893/random-forest-with-bootstrap-false-in-scikit-learn-python)

> The benefit of random forests comes from its creating a large variety of trees by sampling both observations and features. Bootstrap = False is telling it to sample observations with or without replacement - it should still sample when it's False, just without replacement... You tell it what share of features you want to sample by setting max_features..

Comment: So correct me If i'm wrong but if `bootstrap=True` then for every tree we pick random sample of data but rows from one tree may also present in another tree but if we choose `bootstrap=False` everything will be unique. If I'm not correct can you explain it in simpler term.

Answer (score 1):

The newer documentation clears this up:

> **bootstrap : *boolean, optional (default=True)***
>
> Whether bootstrap samples are used when building trees. If False, the whole datset is used to build each tree.

Setting it to False makes the random subsetting of features the only randomness; every tree sees the entire training dataset.